# Lists - Separate Views for External Users

Tags: list, permissions

First off - some what new to Sharepoint.

Creating lists to manage some dynamic data etc.

We share this list with external users (clients).

I understand views for the most part. Non-public views are just for you only.

Looking to have views that are only visible to the external users. Can you do this?  I can’t see an obvious way to do this currently.